# Push notifications in Laravel 9 and PWA

Tags: laravel, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, laravel-9, web-push

currently in our PWA application we use the `laravel-notification-channels/webpush` package, but the client would like users to also receive notifications when they log out of the application. Is there any reasonable solution to send notifications, e.g. to devices on which the client was logged in and accepted the notifications even though he was not logged in at the time?

Comment: If it's ok to use a SaaS, it would be simple to build that. For example, using Pushpad, you can call `pushpad('uid')` to attach a user ID to the push subscription when the user logs in to your website. Then the uid remains there, until you remove it explicitly. So you can still send push messages to the user even after the log out. It also has a PHP library.